# breezejs: removing validation rules

Tags: breeze

I would like to remove validations rules from the metadataStore. In the documentation it is mentionned that :

> 'For most applications, you must wait untl the client has retrieved
>   metadata from the server. You can fetch that metadata explicitly or
>   wait until Breeze gets it implicitly during the first query.'

I would like to remove the validation rule from the constructor registered with registerEntityTypeCtor as I believe it is a good place for doing so. But this function is called for every entities and the code for removing the validation rule should only be executed once, no need to call it each time an entity is created. Therefore, how can I do that only for the very first time the metadata is fetched ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach for this is to initiate the metadata fetch yourself. i.e. call *EntityManager.fetchMetadata* and perform your removals within the 'then' portion of the call.

```
myEntityManager.fetchMetadata().then( function() {
   // perform your removals here.
}
```

Breeze will automatically perform this call during the first query, *if it has not already been made*.

Comment: I've tried doing exactly that already in a service constructor where I configure the breeze datamanager. The problem is that this code is called implicitly by the AngularJS dependency resolver when the service is injected in my controller (I know we are a bit off-topic here because I use AngularJS). When the promise returns, it's already too late as the calling code did not wait for the promise to resolve. Do you have any idea how I could do it the way I've explained in my post ?

Comment: Not sure I understand, even if Angular resolves dependencies early, you won't have an issue unless/until the first query is executed. And this IS under your control, isn't it? I'm probably misinterpreting your question and ... I'm not sure I understand the dependencies and order of execution for your app. But if you really want to remove the validation in the ctor you can set your own 'validationsRemoved' flag on the entityType to indicate whether you have 'cleared' validations and check this flag each time the ctor is called.  The first call will remove the validations and then set the flag.

Comment: yes, the problem is quite specific to my own code actually. It doesn't matter, I'll figure it out. However, just a thought but wouldn't it be great to have way to find out that metadata has come back from the server for the first time ? An event handler could then be triggered for handling stuff like adding/removing validation rules.